# Copying part of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a graph data structure for which I need to copy some part of it. Each node has at most two children, and for the sake of the question can be assumed to be represented like this:

```
struct node {
    int type;
    struct node *child1, *child2;
};
```

The type field indicates (in leaves only) whether the node must be copied, must not be copied, or may be copied.

I am given a root node, and need to return a copy of the subgraph reachable from that node. Certain leaf nodes must be copied, and certain leaf nodes must be shared with the original graph. Since the original graph must not be corrupted, a non-leaf node must be copied if any of its children must be. Obviously, I would prefer to copy only those nodes that I must copy in order to satisfy the requirements, though the requirements would be satisfied by copying all non-leaf nodes.

Copying only the minimal set would be trivial for a tree, but this graph may contain cycles. Is there an efficient algorithm for copying only the nodes that are required? In particular, one that doesn't require calculating all the parent pointers or iterating until a fixed point is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify [Tarjan's SCC algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) slightly to detect whether each strongly connected component requires a copy. The pseudocode executes lines

```
strongconnect(w)
v.lowlink := min(v.lowlink, w.lowlink)
```

for each tree edge `vw` of the depth-first search, to which you can add

```
v.needscopy := v.needscopy or w.needscopy
```

The `needscopy` field will be accurate for the SCC root when it's time to pop the component off of the stack. The stack effectively is constructing some of the parent pointers, but perhaps it would be more acceptable to you.

Comment: With regard to the parent pointers, I was mainly concerned with the possibility of needing to store a variable sized array of pointers on each node. Your solution is totally acceptable for my usage.